# iterated clauses

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction

It is common to have a which clause.

The problem, is it okay or common to have an iterated which clause?

Below is what I am going to write:

> Underlying the cusps is an exactly solvable model, which consists of equally spaced levels extending from -∞ to +∞, between which two arbitrary levels are coupled to each other by the same strength.

Is it ok?

Comment: Why would you think it is not OK?

Comment: @MorganFR Because it is rare.

Comment: It is not that rare, repetition of words happen a lot, like "which", "that", "for", "of", etc. There is nothing wrong about it. Also consider https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffalo_buffalo_Buffalo_buffalo_buffalo_buffalo_Buffalo_buffalo and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_while_John_had_had_had_had_had_had_had_had_had_had_had_a_better_effect_on_the_teacher

Comment: Agreed. I think the use of *which* in your example sentence sounds perfectly natural. I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "Underlying the cusps", but that is a different question.

Comment: If each _which_ has its referent, use as many as you wish.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing technically wrong with the sentence.

However, it might be helpful to chunk the information more finely and improve readability. Long sentences are common in academic writing and a pain to read.

> Underlying the cusps is an exactly solvable model consisting of equally spaced levels extending from -∞ to +∞. Any two arbitrary levels are coupled to each other by the same strength.